# Stata: egen rowpctile a range of values instead of single percentile value

Tags: stata, missing-data, percentile

I have a variable `var` with many missing values for which I want to calculate the 95th percentile then use this value to drop observations that lie above the 95th percentile (for those observations that are not missing the variable).

Because of the many missing values, I use `egen` with `rowpctile` which is supposed to calculate the `p(#)` percentile, ignoring missing values. When I look at the p95 values, however, they're a range of different values rather than a single 95th percentile value as seen below:

```
. egen p95 = rowpctile(var), p(95)

. list p95

     +-----------+
     |       p95 |
     |-----------|
  1. |         . |
  2. |  65.71429 |
  3. |  14.28571 |
  4. |         . |
  5. |         . |
...
```

Am I using the function incorrectly or is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: There is usually a better way to analyse data than throwing out the highest 5%.

Comment: Agreed @NickCox. This is for an assignment, however, so I have to do as requested, though I plan on including some exposition on more rigorous ways of identifying outliers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rowpctile` function of the `egen` command calculates the percentile of the values of a list of variables **separately for each observation**. Here is some technique which should set you on the right path.

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. replace price = . in 1/5
(5 real changes made, 5 to missing)

. summarize price, detail

                            Price
-------------------------------------------------------------
      Percentiles      Smallest
 1%         3291           3291
 5%         3748           3299
10%         3895           3667       Obs                  69
25%         4296           3748       Sum of Wgt.          69

50%         5104                      Mean           6245.493
                        Largest       Std. Dev.      3015.072
75%         6342          13466
90%        11497          13594       Variance        9090661
95%        13466          14500       Skewness       1.594391
99%        15906          15906       Kurtosis       4.555704

. display r(p95)
13466

. generate toobig = price>r(p95)

. list make price if toobig | price==.

     +---------------------------+
     | make                price |
     |---------------------------|
  1. | AMC Concord             . |
  2. | AMC Pacer               . |
  3. | AMC Spirit              . |
  4. | Buick Century           . |
  5. | Buick Electra           . |
     |---------------------------|
 12. | Cad. Eldorado      14,500 |
 13. | Cad. Seville       15,906 |
 27. | Linc. Mark V       13,594 |
     +---------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to adapt that to work out perfectly.